# For which $a$ does $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (1+x^a)}{x-\sin x}dx$ converge

Tags: calculus, analysis

Here is what I've been able to do deduce so far.

Since function $\sin(1+x^a)$ isn't non negative neither for $x$ from $0$ to $1$ nor $x$ from $1$ to $\infty $ we won't be able to use limit test.

That leaves us with majorant and dirichlet/abel criterion.

For $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin (1+x^a)}{x-\sin x}dx$ if we take $a \le1$ then $(\sin (1+x^a))'= \cos(1+x^a) ax^{a-1}$ is bounded and $\frac{1}{x-\sin x}$ aprroaches zero so integral is convergent.

I cant figure out what to do if $a \gt 1$ and I obviously can't use Dirichlet criterion for
$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin (1+x^a)}{x-\sin x}dx$.
I suppose that means that I should use majorant criterion but I can't think of any expression that would be helpful to compare to.

Comment: If $a\geq 0$, you have a non-integrable singularity at $x=0+$.

Comment: What does that mean? I've never heard of that term before (English isn't my native so maybe we use diferent terms)

Comment: If $a\geq 1$ then $\frac{{\sin (1 + x^a )}}{{x - \sin x}} \sim \frac{{6\sin (1)}}{{x^3 }}$ near $x=0$ and $\frac{1}{x^3}$ is not integrable at $x=0+$.